# Can I use "onward" as in "from now on"?

Tags: word-usage

> I don't like the word X, so I'm going to use Y onward.

This doesn't sound broken, would it be normal to use in common speech?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Onward" is not commonly used in speech, "from now on" is much more idiomatic.

Answer (score -1):

**onwards** or **onward**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/onwards)

adv

> at or towards a point or position ahead, in advance, etc

Your sentence suing onward with modification:

> I never liked using X. Onwards (onward), I shall use Y.

Other phrases or idioms may work better and find more usage.